# Reactive Spring Security Oauth2 : invalid redirect url

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured a redirect url in application.yml file. It is throwing 404 error

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          test:
            client-id: xxx
            client-secret: xxx
            scope: email
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code            
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/kp/oauth2/redirect
```

It is working fine when redirect url is

> http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/redirect

Is there any pattern in constructing redirect url?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spring's oauth2 feature, and spring is the one completing OAuth2 complete flow for you, which includes redirection URI, you can't give your own URI
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/redirect this is the default URI.

FYI you don't have to mention redirect-URI in the first place as it is the default.

On the other hand, if you want to manually complete the OAuth2 flow you have can give a custom redirect URI, you just have to make that redirect URI as your endpoint manually and code the flow yourself.